# Python tkinter loading in progress

Tags: python, tkinter, load

I would like to know how to display the text "loading in progress" while the final text is loading after pressing the execute button?

```
import time
import random
import tkinter as tk


def load():
    my_label.config(text="Loading in progress...")  #how to display it?
    my_time = random.randint(1,10)
    time.sleep(my_time)
    my_label.config(text="Loaded!!!")

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')

my_button = tk.Button(root, text='Load', width=20, command=load)
my_button.pack(pady=20)

my_label = tk.Label(root, text='')
my_label.pack(pady=20)


root.mainloop()
```

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Use .after instead of sleep in tkinter to avoid blocking the main loop.

```
import time
import random
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

my_time = None

def load(my_time):
    if my_time is None:
        my_time = random.randint(2, 10)
    my_label.config(text=f"Loading in progress...{my_time}")
    my_time -=1
    timer = root.after(1000, load, my_time)
    if not my_time:
        root.after_cancel(timer)
        my_label.config(text="Loaded!!!")


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')

my_button = tk.Button(root, text='Load', width=20, command=partial(load, my_time))
my_button.pack(pady=20)

my_label = tk.Label(root, text='')
my_label.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```